# Tikz: Add label to -| path

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to add a label to the long line?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5.123456789cm]
\node (a) {a};
\node (b) [right of=a] {b};

\draw (a) -- +(0,1) -| (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 \draw (a) -- +(0,1) -| node[pos=0.25,above] {foo} (b);
```

In a `-|`/`|-` path, `midway`/`pos=0.5` is at the break point, so `pos=0.25` is halfway along the first segment.

Note by the way that the `right of=<other node>` syntax is considered deprecated, it is usually recommended to add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, and then say `right=of <other node>` instead. A difference is that the distance by default is measured between the node edges, instead of node centers. With the `on grid` option the distance is between node centers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5.123456789cm]
\node (a) {a};
\node (b) [right=of a] {b};

\draw (a) -- +(0,1) -| node[pos=0.25,above] {foo} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5.123456789cm]
\node (a) {a};
% with on grid 5.12345789cm is from the center of a to the center of b
\node (b) [on grid,right=of a] {b};

\draw (a) -- +(0,1) -| node[pos=0.25,above] {foo} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```